# SQL Error log Time Gap

Tags: sql, error-log

The question is more towards the possible causes why SQL error log stops logging. In my scenario, checked the System/Applications logs for any crash or service stopped events and it was all clear.
The last timestamp in the log was 8:53 Am and it straight away jumps to 6:50 PM, close to 9hrs of gap with no information. And Database connectivity issue with the application as reported starts around 2:40 PM.[Snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ryeff.jpg)

Security patches were applied the previous day and the server was rebooted at 6:20 AM.
Ultimately, SQL services were restarted to regain connectivity.

I suspect the patch but Anyone has any idea how and why would SQL server stop logging?

Comment: What are you trying to ask from a Software developer? Go and try https://serverfault.com/ , but what do you expect? We don't know what your system looks like, we don't have any insights or access to your server.

Comment: Which [DBMS product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: thanks for the response, its SQL Database @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: "SQL" is a query language, not a database product. Every relational database is a "SQL database"

Answer (score 0):

So i have the same issue, the last log i have is from Saturday then nothing till we restarted it on Monday.

we also applied "updated with the Windows Update to SQL Server 2016 SP1 Cumulative Update (CU) 8 KB4077064"on Saturday

the last error i have is 
"An error occurred while trying to flush all running Extended Event sessions.  Some events may be lost."

Comment: Good to know i am not the only one here...i did see some SSL related error in SQL error log after which it went dead..not sure how related it is.

Error: 17182, Severity: 16, State: 1.
Error: 17826, Severity: 18, State: 3.
Error: 17120, Severity: 16, State: 1

See if you have this logged in your error log before the log stops logging.